# How do I hide UITableView when no data from core data to fetch [Swift]

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, core-data

How do I hide UITableview when bookmark has not yet been done but “instead” show a label with a message “you have not yet bookmark anything”. I have tried to check data in core data whether it is empty or not but, unfortunately, it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            if fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count == 0 {
            self.tableView.isHidden = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if the Core Database is empty you have to make a `NSFetchRequest` on the entity you want to check, and check if the results of the request are empty.

**You can check it with this function:**

```
func entityIsEmpty(entity: String) -> Bool
{

    var appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    var context = NSManagedObjectContext()

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
    var error = NSErrorPointer()

    var results:NSArray? = self.context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: error)

    if let res = results
    {
        if res.count == 0
        {
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }
    }
    else
    {
        println("Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
        return true
    }

}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to handle this in your table view data source. Show a different cell with the info you want if there are 0 records. You could also hide the table view and show a label instead if you prefer.

In `numberOfRowsInSection`, check for 0 and return 1 anyway. (Assuming you have no sections.)

```
let count = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count
return count > 0 ?? count : 1
```

Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` make sure you display the correct info.

```
if fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count == 0 {
   // initialize a different cell
   return cell
}
// configure and return usual cell
```